# Need help understanding and adapting this algorithm for hash table

Tags: c, algorithm, hashtable

I am implementing a hashtable as an exercise and need to create some function that will enlarge the hash-map when the load exceeds 1.5, or when the count of entries in the hashtable/the count of buckets exceeds 1.5

I have found this other implementation of hashtable. However, the difference is that I am using buckets that point to cells (created dynamically in runtime) that are all linked to eachother as a linked list. The implementation uses a hashtable with pre-allocated structs instead.

So it looks a bit like [ bucket ] --> [ cell of memory ] --> [ cell of memory ] --> [cell of memory]

Here is the implementation found:

```
static void expandIfNecessary(Hashmap* map) {
// If the load factor exceeds 0.75...
if (map->size > (map->bucketCount * 3 / 4)) {
    // Start off with a 0.33 load factor.
    size_t newBucketCount = map->bucketCount << 1;
    Entry** newBuckets = calloc(newBucketCount, sizeof(Entry*));
    if (newBuckets == NULL) {
        // Abort expansion.
        return;
    }

    // Move over existing entries.
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < map->bucketCount; i++) {
        Entry* entry = map->buckets[i];
        while (entry != NULL) {
            Entry* next = entry->next;
            size_t index = calculateIndex(newBucketCount, entry->hash);
            entry->next = newBuckets[index];
            newBuckets[index] = entry;
            entry = next;
        }
    }

    // Copy over internals.
    free(map->buckets);
    map->buckets = newBuckets;
    map->bucketCount = newBucketCount;
}
}
```

Most of it is applicable, except this part:

```
        while (entry != NULL) {
            Entry* next = entry->next;
            size_t index = calculateIndex(newBucketCount, entry->hash);
            entry->next = newBuckets[index];
            newBuckets[index] = entry;
            entry = next;
        }
```

Presumably, I want to ensure that the linked list is broken apart so that the entries are still connected properly. I am also a bit fuzzy on understanding exactly what is going on here.

My attempt at this would look like:

```
         while (entry != NULL) { 
                    // use the pointer of this cell to get to the next cell, store this in a pointer called next
                    // hash the key of the current entry
                    ...
```

**This is the part where I start not understanding the implementation and where I'm not sure what to do with my linked list. How do I apply this? Can you explain how to adapt it?**

Comment: Please specify what you need to clarify? The concept of the hashtables or the current implementation of using an existing key?

Comment: @YuryLapitsky I need to know how to apply this implementation to my particular data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Hash table items are repositioned to new buckets/bins when the hash is enlarged:

```
old_index = item->hash % old_bucket_count    
new_index = item->hash % new_bucket_count
```

This implementation stored the hash value of each item in `entry->hash` for performance sake.
What's being done is take out an item, find its new index (bucket) and place it at the front of the linked list of that bucket.

Comment: This is what I don't understand specifically: entry->next = newBuckets[index]; newBuckets[index] = entry;

Comment: I "drew" out a diagram in the question at the top.

Comment: You drew a diagram of a linked list.